# ANSI-encode string for saving in database

Tags: c#, database, character-encoding

I'm working on a crawler that opens files and parses them and puts the content into a database.

However I've had a problem with files that contains odd chars, and I was wondering if there is any simple way to enforce ANSI-encoding of the string before I put it into the database, so to make sure that there is no illegal chars.

The project is written in C#, and the code I use to put stuff into the database is as following:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TaIndex (IndexId, IndexTekst, IndexDato, IndexModulId, IndexModul, IndexFilsti) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = newIdGetter();
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexTekst", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexDato", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime;
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexModulId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ModuleId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexModul", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Module;
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexFilsti", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ((object)FilePath) ?? DBNull.Value;
```

The problem is with the IndexTekst-field, which comes from the files.

Comment: Don't mess with this.  Make the dbase column type nvarchar and instantly solve all your problems.

Comment: The db-field isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could always check that the string can be encoded and then re-decoded to the same value:

```
public static bool CanBeRoundTripped(Encoding encoding, string text)
{
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    string decoded = encoding.GetString(bytes);
    return text == decoded;
}
```

Call that on each text field before saving it - and then consider what to do if it fails...

Is there any way you can change the database schema to accept all Unicode characters? That would be a far more pleasant approach, IMO.

If you *do* need to use some sort of ANSI encoding, you should work out *exactly* which encoding you mean. There are lots of encodings which are generally called "ANSI". You need to work out which code page you mean.

Comment: Should probably do check which encoding it. As of now I use Encoding.Default, but it's only to be run on one server, so it shouldn't cause too much trouble. And I don't really care if some illegal chars are removed (in other words, the `text == decoded` is not needed). The db is MSACCESS and it's having problems with displaying and more importantly deleting data from the designer (this is a requirement unfortunately) when the data contains chars that's not in the ansi-set. Both INSERT and SELECT works well, but DELETE and UPDATE have troubles. So I just wanted to strip all illegal chars out.

Comment: I actually ended up with an extension-method: `public static string ToAnsi(this string s) { return Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)); }`. I know it's not a "good" solution, but it works, and right now that's the important part.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("IndexTekst", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Encoding.Default.GetString(Text);
```

Or maybe specifically convert it between the different encodings with `Encoding.Convert()`

Comment: GetString doesn't take a string - it takes bytes. I would also strongly advise *against* using Encoding.Default - it should be a *specified* encoding rather than whatever the system default happens to be. That may well *not* be the same as the database collation.